# Codeigntier : Post data not working in Codeigntier apis

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, postman

i am using following code to test posting of data but post data is always empty i tried to test using postman but it did not work , following is a test code that i wrote but it always goes to else block , i tried writing else if as well but it did not work

```
class Api_home extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('Api_model','api');
        $this->load->helper('form');
            $data= array(
                'message'   => ' Something went wrong', 
                'status'    =>1, 
                'data'      =>'', 
            ); 
    }
        public function test(){

            $lang= $this->input->post['lang'];
            if($lang=="ar"){
                $this->data['message']= 'Arabic test';
            } 
                    //else if 
                   // else if($lang=="en")
            else{
                $this->data['message']= 'English test';
            }
            $data['status']= 1 ; 


            echo json_encode($data,true); 
                    die;
    }
```

it always goes to en version even if i post ar , if i do var_dump for posted data it gives me false . Please advise how can i sort it

i always get following response

Comment: `$lang= $this->input->post['lang'];` is wrong , correct is `$lang= $this->input->post('lang');`

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I'm working on a CI project atm so it wasn't too much effort to test this.

Firstly, you have used the wrong brackets for `$lang = $this->input->post['lang'];` so it just isn't happy, but doesn't throw an error, no idea why.

You should change it to:

`$lang = $this->input->post('lang');` Note the curved brackets.

Secondly, I'm not sure if it's intentional or not but you actually have 2 different `$data` variables going on:

`$this->data` and `$data`. So `echo json_encode($data, true);` shows only what it contains, perhaps you meant `echo json_encode($this->data, true);`

Finally, the code snippet above is missing a final closing curly brace, hopefully it's not missing from the source!

I hope this helps solve your problem =)

Answer (score 0):

try return json_output:

```
 public function test(){
   $lang= $this->input->post['lang'];
            if($lang=="ar"){
                $message= 'Arabic test';
return parent::json_output(['code' => '1', 'message' => 'Succesful', 'data' => $message]);
            } 
                    //else if 
                   // else if($lang=="en")
            else{
                $message= 'English test';
return parent::json_output(['code' => '2', 'message' => 'Succesful', 'data' => $message]);
            }
            $data['status']= 1 ; 
  echo json_encode($data,true); 
                    die;
    }
```